# Spectral gap and Ising model

Tags: ising-model, spin-models

Consider an instance of the Ising model, with $N$ number of spins on a 2D square lattice (or any other 2D structure) wrapped into a torus to avoid boundary conditions (in other words, periodic boundary conditions) with nearest neighbor coupling.
I am sampling from the Boltzmann probability distribution: $$\mu(s)=\frac{e^{-E(s)/T}}{Z}$$
using Monte Carlo Markov chains (MCMC). $Z$ is the partition function, $s$ is a spin configuration ($s\in S$ with $S$ state space containing all the possible spin configurations for the $N$ spins system), and $E(s)$ is the energy whose definition depends on the specific instance of the model.

Consider the following transition matrix P representing the MC process:
$$P(s'|s)=A(s'|s)C(s'|s)$$
where $C$ is the proposal strategy and $A$ is the acceptance probability (Metropolis-Hastings):$$A(s'|s)=min(1, \frac{\mu(s')C(s|s')}{\mu(s)C(s'|s)})$$
$C$ can be any (good) proposal distribution such that $P$ satisfies the detailed balance condition:
$$P(s'|s)\mu(s)=P(s|s')\mu(s')$$

The MCMC transition matrix $P$ defines the spectral gap:

$$\delta=1-\lambda$$

where $\lambda$ is the second largest eigenvalue of $P$. The spectral gap is an important measure of how fast the Markov chain converges to the target probability distribution (Boltzmann probability in this case). It is also directly related to other important quantities as the relaxation time and the exponential autocorrelation time.

Given a certain $C$, I am trying to understand the relationship between the system dimension, the number of spins $N$, and the spectral gap $\delta$. How does $\delta$ scale with respect to the number of spins $N$? Could someone please suggest relevant literature regarding this relationship?

Any information about the relationship between the relaxation time or the autocorrelation time and the number of spins $N$ would be equally helpful.

Information about the scaling of the mixing time with respect to the number of spins $N$ could help as well. The mixing time is not directly related to the spectral gap but it can be used to calculate upper and lower bounds.

Comment: I think that you should also specify the boundary conditions you are interested in, as these can have an enormous impact on the spectral gap in the phase coexistence regime.

Comment: @YvanVelenik thank you for your comment. I edited the question specifying periodic boundary conditions. However, any kind of lead on this topic, even if it doesn't involve periodic boundary conditions, would be really helpful.

Comment: Careful, there is a difference between mixing time and relaxation time. The relaxation time applies when you are in equilibrium and is related to the inverse gap. The mixing time is what you are typically interested in, and often dwarfs the relaxation time. In the case of the Ising model, these quantities depend on the choice of the MCMC algorithm, are you assuming Glauber dynamics?

Answer (score 1):

In general, closed form expression are hard to come by. You can try to empirically check the trend, but there are some theoretical results based on mean field theory. Also the scaling in $N$ depends crucially on the phase you are in (critical point, ordered/disordered phase).

A general method is to identify the master equation describing your MCMC with a Schrödinger equation (in imaginary time) of an appropriately chosen quantum system. Depending on your background, this could help form an intuition.

Typically, when you have $N$ classical Ising spin sites, your ensemble is a probability distribution $P$ over the space $\{\pm\}^N$. It is natural to view it as ket $|\psi\rangle$ of the Hilbert space of $N$ spin 1/2 particles. Each classical spin configuration is a simultaneous eigenstate of the $\sigma^z_i$.

The energy of a classical configuration is given by the observable:
$$
H_0=-J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\sigma^z_i\sigma^z_j
$$

and a spin flip at site $i$ is done by $\sigma_i^x$ and the variation of energy for a flip at $i$ is given by:
$$
\Delta E_i = \sigma_i^xH_0\sigma_i^x-H_0 =-2J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\sigma^z_i\sigma^z_j
$$
Your can now write your master equation as:
$$
\frac{d}{d\tau}|\psi\rangle =-H|\psi\rangle
$$
where the gap is given by the difference in energy of the ground-state and the first excited state (the ground state has energy $0$ since it is the stationary state, so it is directly the first excited state’s energy).

For most MCMC algorithms, the Hamiltonian is of the form:
$$
H=\sum_i \sigma_x^if(\Delta E_i)
$$
where $f$ depends on the algorithm. For Metropolis-Hastings, you’ll get the awkward minimum of ratio function, but for Glauber dynamics, you’ll get exponentials.

Using this analogy, the simplest case of a MCMC of a 1D classical spin chain is mapped to a 1D quantum Ising spin chain, which is solvable but requires heavy machinery (Onsager’s solution). The most reasonable objective is mean field, ie a complete graph (Curie-Weiss model), but even then, it is quite complicated.

While it is tempting to use naive extensivity arguments, they do not always work. It typically does not work at the critical point. Indeed, you are interested in the large system limit, but what is the reference size it needs to be compared to? It turns out that it is the correlation length $\xi$, which diverges at the critical temperature (which is often what you are interested in sampling). It turns out that in this case, the relevant quantity is the dynamical critical exponent $z$ given by the relation with the relaxation time:
$$
\tau\sim\xi^z
$$

In the ordered phase, things are worst still. Due to the existence of the double dip in free energy (all up/all down) you’d expect exponentially diverging relaxation time in system size by analogy with Arrhenius’ law.

For check out for example appendix D 4. of [“Large deviations for the Skew-Detailed-Balance Lifted-Markov processes to sample the equilibrium distribution of the Curie-Weiss model”](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09429.pdf) or “Critical slowing down and nonlinear response in an exactly solvable stochastic model” by Ruijgrok and Tjon.

Hope this helps.